# Getting error Missing artifact spring-web:org.springframework in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to create Spring 4 MVC maven based project into Eclipse Neon.
The problem is that when I am trying to add dependency into pom.xml, I am getting error:

> Missing artifact spring-web:org.springframework:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>org.springframework</artifactId>
        <groupId>spring-webmvc</groupId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>org.springframework</artifactId>
        <groupId>spring-context</groupId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>org.springframework</artifactId>
        <groupId>spring-aop</groupId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>org.springframework</artifactId>
        <groupId>spring-web</groupId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I look into .m2 directory, I was having all the dependencies downloaded. I am not getting then why is it happening ? Help me.

Comment: I guess you should include `spring-core` artifact as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't those maven xml strophes wrong?  You reversed the artifact and groupId key values. Shouldn't they look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```